# Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\classes\session.php on line 10

Tags: php, oop, session, offset

I have this code below with error of illegal offset on line 10 as indicated below: I will be happy if someone can tell me what's wrong. I can't figure it out.I have checked throw  all this to find what's wrong.

```
<?php 
       class Session{
      public static function exists($name){
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name]))?true:false; 
     }
     public static function put($name,$value){
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
     }
     public static function get($name){
        return $_SESSION[$name];//This line has illegal offset
     }
     public static function delete($name){
        if(self::exists($name)){
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        } 
     }
     public static function flash($name,$string = null){
         if(self::exists($name)){
             $session = self::get($name);
             self::delete($name);
             return $session;
         }else{
             self::put($name,$string);
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: I think you should pass only name instead of $name..

Comment: try to pass default value:  `public static function get($name = null){... }`

Comment: What code are you using to test this, @Kwasi? Aside from the problem in the `put()` method, which Anant has fixed for you, I am not sure I can see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
'session' => array(
        'session' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
        )
```

with this

```
'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
    )
```

in init.php